# Not Authorized error while creating a MultiUserChat room

Tags: xmpp, smack, asmack, multiuserchat

I am trying to create a instant chat room using Smack but the server returns me an IQ packet with an error code 401 and type="AUTH" and a message packet with a message that the room is locked from entry until configuration is confirmed

```
final MultiUserChat muc = new MultiUserChat(connection, chatName+"@conference.123");
try {
     muc.sendConfigurationForm(new Form(Form.TYPE_SUBMIT));
     muc.create(chatName);
     } catch (XMPPException e) {
        Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage());
     }
```

This gives an exception (not-authorized(401)).
Following are the two packets received from server:

```
<iq id="J1O5y-5" to="akshay@123/Smack" from="test@conference.123" type="error"><error code="401" type="AUTH"><not-authorized xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></iq>
```

and

```
<message to="akshay@123/Smack" from="test@conference.123" type="groupchat"><body>This room is locked from entry until configuration is confirmed.</body></message>
```

So are there any changes in server configuration that I need to make or is there any problem in code ?

Answer (score 0):

How about changing the order as below:

```
muc.create(nickName);
muc.sendConfigurationForm(new Form(Form.TYPE_SUBMIT));
```

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me. Please try this.

```
public void createRoom(String r,String n) throws XMPPException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String t = r + "@conference.localhost";

    MultiUserChat muc = new MultiUserChat(connection, t);

    muc.create(n);

    muc.sendConfigurationForm(new Form(Form.TYPE_SUBMIT));

}
```